# RoR Create and Update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Galera, estou desenvolvendo um sistema em ROR e tenho uma tabela de noticias no banco, sendo de que existe uma coluna destaque e toda vez que o admin cadastrar outra noticia como destaque mesmo já existindo uma no banco, o controlador tem que remover a que já estava como destaque e colocar essa nova. OBS: O campo destaque é Boolean então ele só vai mudar de "true" para "false".

Controller

```
def create
    # @notice = Notice.new(notice_params)
    featured = params[:notice][:featured]
    category = params[:notice][:category_id]
    user = current_user.secretary.prefecture.county_id
      if featured = 1
        @notice = Notice.where(county_id: user, category_id: category,  featured: true)
        if @notice.present?
          @notice = Notice.find(@notice.id).update(featured: false) rescue nil
        end
      end
 end
```

Comment: e qual a sua dúvida mesmo? qual o erro?

Comment: Olá Ricardo, muito obrigado por ter perguntado, mas eu já consegui resolver. Eu queria cadastrar uma noticia com destaque e se já existisse uma com destaque na mesma categoria ele iria remover o destaque da que já existia e adicionar a nova noticia como destaque.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de muito tentar consegui executar. Obrigado!

```
  def create
  featured = params[:notice][:featured]
  puts featured
  category = params[:notice][:category_id]
  user = current_user.secretary.prefecture.county_id

    if featured.to_s == "1"
      puts "destaque selecionado, buscando destaque ativo"
      @n = Notice.where(county_id: user, category_id: category,  featured: true)
      # b = @n
      puts "Registo encontrado ", @n.ids
      if !@n.empty?
        puts "A busca n foi vazia"
        a = @n.where(id: @n.ids).update(featured: false)
        puts "O registo ", @n.ids, " foi alterado"
      end
    end
    @notice = Notice.new(notice_params)
    @notice.county_id = user
      respond_to do |format|
      if @notice.save
          format.html { redirect_to action: :index}
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @notice }
        # format.html { redirect_to @notice, notice: 'Notice was successfully created.' }
        # format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @notice }
        else
          format.html { redirect_to action: :index}
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @notice }
        # format.html { render :new }
        # format.json { render json: @notice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
  end
```